# Break out of while True loop with function

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

So I have a while true loop -

```
while True:
  getStatus()
  print('Ended')
```

I hope to be able to break out of it if answer is 999. this is what I tried:

```
def getStatus():
  answer = input('What is the box ID? ')
  if answer == 999:
    return False 
  elif type(answer) == int:
    boxId = answer + 1
    print(boxId)
```

However even when the input is '999' it loops back and asks 'What is the box ID? ' again.

How do I get out of the while true loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449433/4909087

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I don't think using `input` is the real problem in this question. In Python 2, `input` will return a number and the `getStatus` function should more or less work (it will either return `False` or `None`, which isn't a very good way to distinguish success from failure). Though `print` isn't a function in Python 2, so who knows what version is really being used. Anyway, I'm going to reopen.

Comment: @Blckknght On closer inspection... yes, I think it is a problem of `getStatus`' return value not being tested in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` loop keeps looping because that's exactly what you've told it to do. After the function you call from its body returns, you ignore the return value, unconditionally print `"Ended"` and then do it all again, since the condition on the loop is obviously still truthy.

If you want the function to control if the loop keeps going, you should use its return value as the condition in the loop, with something like this:

```
running = True
while running:
    running = getStatus()
print("Ended") # move this outside the loop!
```

This requires that `getStatus` returns a truthy value when you want to keep looping and a falsey value when you want to stop. Your current implementation of that function doesn't do that. It returns `False` when `999` is entered, but doesn't explicitly return anything if you give other input (which in Python is equivalent to returning `None`). Since both `False` and `None` are falsey, the code above won't actually work (you could patch it with something like `running = getStatus() is None`, but that would be horrible). You should change the function to have an explicit `return` statement in all of its branches (including the case for non-integer inputs, where it doesn't go into either your `if` or `elif` blocks).

If the loop and the function's logic are tightly intertwined, it might make sense to move the loop into the function itself, rather than having it be separate and needing to use a return value to signal when to stop. In a single function, you can use `break` to exit a loop directly:

```
def getStatus():
    while True:
        answer = input('What is the box ID? ')
        if answer == 999:
            break
        elif isinstance(answer, int): # isinsance() is better than type(...) == ...
            boxId = answer + 1
            print(boxId)
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.") # still good to handle this case
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add if statement before get_status() that will check if it's true and break and in the get_status function you will have to return true to break

```
def getStatus():
  answer = input('What is the box ID? ')
  if answer == 999:
    return True
  elif type(answer) == int:
    boxId = answer + 1
    print(boxId)


while True:
  if getStatus():
     print('Ended')
     break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def selectedCountry():
    while True:
        country = input("Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:  ").upper()
        if country == str("HR") or country == str("RO") or country == str("RS"):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter HR or RO or RS: " + "you wrote: " + country)
```

Why while True is working outside of a function and inside the same problem with asking again

```
Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:  >? hr
Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:
```

Comment: Hello @user2498462, to make your answer more understandable you should use the same code that was used in the question.

Comment: Not only is this code quite problematic in terms of logic structure it is also very miss leading during the fact that its ignoring the main problem completly

Answer (score -2):

You may change it to -

```
while True:
  if(getStatus()==False):
      print('Ended')
      break
```

By this you can use returned value to break out of infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can format your code by indenting it by four extra spaces (in addition to whatever indentation you want it to have internally). An easy way to get that is by selecting it in the editor, and clicking the `{}` button. If you have multiple lines selected, it will indent them all for you. If you have a single line (or only part of one), it will use backticks \`\` instead (which are useful for putting code snippets like variable names in your text).

Comment: hi Rohan! may i know which part of my code do i change to yours?

Comment: Sorry @Julliard, I missed the comments. Its too late but still I edited my answer.